# Hibernate JOIN result set

Tags: java, database, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I encountered a problem using Hibernate and Spring MVC, that is, if I run a query with a JOIN inside I get a 500 error without any detail, can someone help me?

The 2 table are:

User:

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "user")
 public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator="increment")
    @GenericGenerator(name="increment", strategy = "increment")
    @Column(name = "id_user")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "surname")
    private String surname;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "contentManager")
    private Set<Project> projects;
    ...
```

Project:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "projects")
    public class Project {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(generator="increment")
        @GenericGenerator(name="increment", strategy = "increment")
        @Column(name = "id_project")
        private Long id;

        @Column(name = "project_name")
        private String name;

        @Column(name = "project_language")
        private String language;

        @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name = "id_content_manager")
        @JsonBackReference
        private User contentManager;

        ...
```

And the controller class method:

```
@Transactional
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody  List<Project> home(Locale locale, Model model) {

    Session session=new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();

    session.beginTransaction();
    List<Project> result = (List<Project>) session.createQuery("FROM projects p JOIN p.contentManager").getResultList();
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();

    return result;
}
```

Can someone help me?

EDIT: tomcat console:

```
WARN : org.hibernate.orm.connections.pooling - HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Hibernate: select project0_.id_project as id_proje1_0_0_, user1_.id_user as id_user1_1_1_, project0_.id_content_manager as id_conte4_0_0_, project0_.project_language as project_2_0_0_, project0_.project_name as project_3_0_0_, user1_.name as name2_1_1_, user1_.surname as surname3_1_1_ from projects project0_ inner join user user1_ on project0_.id_content_manager=user1_.id_user
```

Browser screenshot:
[image]

Comment: You should separate your service layer in different class, that's way you ma get data not found , that is the first thing you should manage.

Comment: You should put some stack trace from tomcat console here in order to get a more specific help.

Comment: @STaefi I just modified adding the console stack too

Comment: Your entity is named `Project`, not `projects`. And I'm pretty sure the join you add to the query won't do what you want it to do. And, most importantly, read the Spring documentation on how to integrate JPA in Spring. What you're doing is completely wrong.

Comment: @JBNizet if I change projects in Project it tells me that Project is not mapped even though I have inserted the mapping on the hibernate.cfg.xml file. Furthermore, if I remove the join, the select query is executed

Comment: Again, read the Spring documentation. You're not supposed to create a configuration: that's Spring's job. You're not supposed to create a SessionFactory: that's Spring's job. And creating a new one at each request is completely insane: this is a very heavyweight operation that must be done once and only once. You're not supposed to begin and commit transactions: that's Spring's job.

Comment: @JBNizetIf I had found what I was looking for in the documentation then I was not here to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
List<?> list = (List<?>) session.createQuery("FROM Project p JOIN p.contentManager").list();
List<Project> result  =  new ArrayList<Project>();  
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    Object[] row = (Object[]) list.get(i);
    Project p = (Project) row[0];
    User s = (User) row[1];
    p.setContentManager(s);
    result.add(p);
}
```